# wordpress programmatically logout everywhere else

Tags: wordpress

How can I logout from every where else this place in wordpress? [not `wp_logout()` because it destroys current session only]

I used this function but it did not work:

```
WP_User_Meta_Session_Tokens::destroy_other_sessions();
```

Comment: Does this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/184164/6003) do what you need?

Comment: i will try that, but how can i destroy all other sessions before the login process?

Comment: and may i know why do people vote my question down?

Answer (score 3):

You must first get the user id, then get the token, protect it and destroy the other sessions. Here's a working example:

```
global $wp_session;
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$session = wp_get_session_token();
$sessions = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance($user_id);
$sessions->destroy_others($session);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version hooked to the `init` action.

```
/**
 * Destroys all sessions for this user except the one with the given token (presumably the one in use).
 */
add_action( 'init', 'destroy_all_other_current_user_sessions' );

function destroy_all_other_current_user_sessions() {

    $manager = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance( get_current_user_id() );

    $manager->destroy_others( wp_get_session_token() );

};
```